# why my second app doesn't want import to first app Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
File "C:\python mini\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1\MyBlog\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mysite.register import views
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.register'
```

Why do you think this error might occur? Why doesn't django see the app being imported? maybe I should try setting up mysite/blog urls?
[image]
project structure:
[image]
settings.py
`

```
from pathlib import Path
import os


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
SECRET_KEY = ''


DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'menu',
    'register.apps.RegisterConfig',

]
```

`mysite/urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from mysite.register import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path("register/", views.register, name="register"),
]
```

`

If i try write just `from register import views`  import underlined in red

Comment: It is the current folder you can simply use `from . import views`

Comment: @SunderamDubey It's doesn't work, views underlined in red

Comment: Can you share your apps.py of register app?

Comment: @SunderamDubey
 '''
from django.apps import AppConfig


class RegisterConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'register'
'''

Comment: I think some problem with IDE itself.

Comment: me to, maybe in django path. Thank you for help

Comment: @SunderamDubey I'm Found the problem.i just swapped 2 lines... `path('', include('blog.urls')), ` with `path("register/", views.register, name="register"),` . At the same time imports are underlined red

Answer (score 0):

I'm Found the problem.I just swapped 2 lines... `path('', include('blog.urls')),`  with `path("register/", views.register, name="register"),` . At the same time import `from register import views` are underlined red

Comment: Is this an answer or additional details to the question?

Comment: @SunderamDubey answer